# Mysql distinct date by month

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have 3 mysql tables:

- members_table(registrationDate    memberId    ageBand scoreBand)
- clicks_table(clickDate    memberId    isApplication   isApproval  revenue ageBand scoreBand)
- activeUsers_table(activityMonth   memberId    ageBand scoreBand   platform)

I'm trying to find the way to get the :

percentage of active users every month for each monthly registration cohort broken out by age.

I can't fine the right manner for find results, can you help please?

Thanks!

Comment: what query have you attempted to use? this is not a "write your code service" it is expected that you demonstrate an attempt.you should also provide `sample data` (reusable, not an image) and the `expected result`

Comment: I tried several queries, like select distinct(DATE_FORMAT(activityMonth ,'%m-%Y')) from activeUsers_table

Comment: and SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(activityMonth ,'&#37;M %y') as month_yy

Comment: For a percentage calculation "select distinct" **IS NOT** going to be useful. Try with a `GROUP BY` clause and the `COUNT()` function. You need at least 2 counts, one for the `for each monthly registration cohort` and another for `active users every month` within those cohorts

Comment: Sample data and desired results would greatly help the question.

Answer (score 0):

I fear your question is difficult to understand, so I'll just offer a hint about how you might proceed.

If you want to write aggregate queries to summarize by month, you can use the [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function. Here's an example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) members, LAST_DAY(registrationDate) registrationMonth
  FROM members_table
 GROUP BY LAST_DAY(registrationDate)
```

You could write several queries like this summarizing different metrics by month. Then, treating the queries like tables, you could join them together.